# Как сделать запрос c условиями в зависимости от значения переменных

Tags: php, sql

[image: форма с отображением данных из таблицы и фильтрацией]

Нужно сделать так чтобы в таблицу загружались данные в зависимости от выбранных значений в `<select>-ах`

если в каком-то из `<select>-ов` значение не выбрано значит оно не используется в условии

данные из `<select>-ов` передаются в переменные так:

```
$ovdrb = $_POST['ovdrb'];
$sub = $_POST['subdivision'];
$type = $_POST['type'];
$manufacture = $_POST['manufacture'];
$model = $_POST['model'];
```

Имеется таблица в БД spravtech c именами столбцов id_ovdrb,id_subdivision, id_type, manufacture, model.

хотелось бы что-то вроде этого : `SELECT * FROM spravtech WHERE id_ovdrb = $ovdrb AND id_subdivision = $sub AND type = $type`, но если в переменной `$type` нет значения, значит оно в условие не включается и отображаются все записи по предыдущему условию, а так бы отображалось с ним и только с конкретным типом указанным в переменной `$type`

Comment: как получить данные из селекта в целом и так было очевидно. вопрос в том, как вы саму выборку делаете.

Comment: у меня есть таблица справочник со столбцами id_ovdrb, id_subdivision, id_type, manufacture, model, хотелось бы чтобы при выборе определенного значения в <Select>-те, например ОВД = 1, загружались данные только с этим  кодом ОВД, а если указано подразделение то с этим подразделением, если же не указано подразделение значит выводились бы все подразделения

Comment: да понятно, и что вам надо сделать, и что таблица у вас есть. Как вы непосредственно в пхп делаете выборку эту? как формируете код запроса, и как его выполняете.

Comment: в том то и дело что я не знаю как написать запрос с использованием переменных если в них хранятся значения, а если нет то не использовать их, отредактировал вопрос, посмотрите, может поймете

Comment: берете заводите условное `$where = " 1 = 1"` , и дальше пишите `if($param) $where .= "AND param = $param"` и так по списку. В итоге получите `$sql = "SELECT ... FROM... WHERE $where"`. Правда подставлять так в запрос не надо, а использовать подготовленные выражения и биндинг параметров.

Comment: Спасибо, примерно понял, но все равно туговато, не могли бы вы как-то более подробнее написать используя мои данные?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Типовой универсальный вариант разбора POST, в случае если в sql запросе нужны только равенства:

```
  $where = array();
  $param = array();
  // Используем массив возможных параметров с их именами в POST и в базе данных
  foreach(["ovdrb" => "id_ovdrb", "sub" => "id_subdivision", "type" => "type"]
          as $local => $db_name) {
      if(isset($_POST[$local])) {
          $where[] = $db_name . '=?';
          $param[] = $_POST[$local];
      }
  }
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM spravtech";
  if(count($where)) {
      $sql = $sql . ' WHERE ' . implode(' AND ', $where);
  }
  // При использовании PDO вызывается так
  $query = $db->prepare($sql);
  $query->execute($param);
```

На выходе получаем запрос на подобии `SELECT * FROM spravtech WHERE id_ovdrb = ? AND id_subdivision = ? AND type = ?` и массив параметров, который можно сразу передать на вход PDO execute или выполнить по нему bind_param для mysqli.
В случае использования не только равенств но и других выражений вроде проверок на больше/меньше или like то можно и не делать универсальный цикл, а по очереди писать условия вроде

```
if(isset($_POST['abc'])) {
    $where[] = "abc_field like ?";
    $param[] = "%".$_POST['abc']."%";
}
```

Главное заполнить массив с условиями для запроса и массив параметров для выполнения синхронно, в одинаковом порядке.

Comment: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on string in, такую ошибку выдает

Comment: @Bastard_Ape Значит у вас $db указывает на на подключение к базе, а содержит какую то строку

Comment: вардампнул $db вывело string(13) "id_tech_sprav", ничего не понимаю, выше в коде тоже через prepare() делаю, там все норм, в те же самые селекты загружаю данные из таблиц и нет проблем

Comment: @Bastard_Ape Так я изначально же не знал как у вас переменные зовутся :) Посмотрите, у меня же цикл обходящий post как раз $db использует, замените там название переменной

Comment: Все разобрался, работает, спасибо вам большое!