# Перезагрузка SQL-запроса

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, sql

Понемногу ознакамливаюсь с тонкостями PHP и MYSQL.
Хочу сделать что-то наподобие фильтра на странице, где выведены все данные из БД. Смысл фильтра в том, чтобы вывести данные из запроса SELECT с ограничением по датам, вместо все таблицы, где выведены все данные без ограничений из той же таблицы.

Данные в таблицу вывожу так

```
$sql = "SELECT item, date, price FROM item_base";
$stmt = $connect_u->prepare($sql); 
$stmt -> execute();
```

Можно ли при помощи JQuery перезагрузить SQL запрос с добавлением ограничений BETWEEN date1 AND date2, чтобы  вывести на той же странице?

Comment: PHP выполняется на сервере, работа с БД происходит на сервере. Сам SQL запрос создается и выполняется на сервере. А JQuery работает на клиенте и все что он может - это передать параметры при запросе сервера, по которым сервер уже построит нужный SQL запрос и выполнит его.

Comment: Пример работы с переменными запроса https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1356353/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81-c-%d1%83%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%8f%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%be%d1%82-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85/1356416#1356416

Comment: при помощи jquery можно отправить ajax запрос (`$.load`)на сервер с указанием дат для фильтрации. Сервер проведет выборку, и вернет html строки таблицы.  а-ля `$("tbody").load("script.php", {d1: .. , d2...})`